# Unable to get focus back on to main window and click on disconnect button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code

After coming back to main window unable to get focus and disconnect button is not getting clicked

```
parent_handle = driver.window_handles[0]

#clicks on  link
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[4]/div/p/a").click()

child_handle = [x for x in driver.window_handles if x != parent_handle][0]
driver.switch_to.window(child_handle)

time.sleep(2)

#will work on this winow

driver.close()

driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
time.sleep(30)

#click on Disconnect button on toolbar on main window
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'btn btn-outline-dark  et-disconnect-link et-disconnect-warning-link')]").click()
```

I tried several ways but getting the below error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(), 'btn btn-outline-dark  et-disconnect-link et-disconnect-warning-link')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
```

Comment: Please review [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the html, but the `xpath` looks like classes, not text

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-outline-dark et-disconnect-link et-disconnect-warning-link')]").click()
```

Or by `css_selector`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-outline-dark.et-disconnect-link.et-disconnect-warning-link").click()
```

You should also use explicit wait instead of `time.sleep(30)`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
# time.sleep(30) -> remove this
element = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-outline-dark  et-disconnect-link et-disconnect-warning-link')]")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were almost there. You need to consider a few more things as follows:

- Assuming initially there is only one `window_handle` opened, instead of `parent_handle = driver.window_handles[0]` you can use **`driver.current_window_handle`**
- Once you close the child window through `driver.close()`, you can use `switch_to.default_content()`.
- `btn btn-outline-dark  et-disconnect-link et-disconnect-warning-link` seems to be the value of `class` attribute.
- As your usecase is to invoke `click()` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
    #clicks on  link
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[4]/div/p/a").click()
    child_handle = [x for x in driver.window_handles if x != parent_handle][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(child_handle)
    #will work on this winow
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
    #click on Disconnect button on toolbar on main window
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-outline-dark..et-disconnect-link.et-disconnect-warning-link"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
    #clicks on  link
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[4]/div/p/a").click()
    child_handle = [x for x in driver.window_handles if x != parent_handle][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(child_handle)
    #will work on this winow
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
    #click on Disconnect button on toolbar on main window
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-outline-dark  et-disconnect-link et-disconnect-warning-link']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```